# Deleting included resources causes XCode to crash/complain

Tags: xcode

If I try to delete some image resources from my (iPhone) XCode project via Finder, XCode will complain with errors on next build that it can't find these files.

If I try to delete them via XCode's 'Delete' command, XCode crashes everytime without fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you didnt copy them into the project (instead of simply reference them) then you may have problems like this, although xcode should not crash when you try deleting them.

Comment: Yeah, I know it is weird.

The files are in the project folder, and I added them via Add to Project command.